# add_menu_page permissions - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: permissions, capabilities, add-menu-page

I am running a fresh install of Wordpress 3.3.2 and the only plugin enabled is one I'm developing, but I can't seem to get past a permissions issue in `add_menu_page`. With the exception of using anonymous functions instead of named functions, I'm following the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) almost exactly.

My plugin source:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Some Plugin
*/

add_action('admin_init', function() {
    add_menu_page('Some Page', 'Some Page', 'manage_options', 'some-slug', function() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    });
});

?>
```

The menu link shows up fine at the bottom of the menu, but instead of "Hello, world!", I see:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I've also tried using the `administrator` capability in place of `manage_options`, but have the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want the `admin_menu` hook, rather than `admin_init`.

Also, you shouldn't use anonymous functions. Instead, use:

```
function wpse51004_add_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('Some Page', 'Some Page', 'manage_options', 'some-slug', 'wpse51004_some_page_callback');
};
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse51004_add_menu_page');

function wpse51004_some_page_callback() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, `admin_menu` is what I was missing. Thanks for catching that! I'll stick with the anonymous functions, though, as my target audience (me) is always on PHP 5.3+. Developing on anything less is an absolute pain and incredibly ugly.

Comment: Ok, but anonymous functions can't be 'unhooked' - so generally speaking (and certainly if for distribution) should be avoided. It's also easier to read/layout code without anonymous callbacks, but that's my personal opinion :)

Comment: Hmmm, good call on the unhooking. If I decide to distribute this one, I'll be sure to wrap up the functions into a class or something. Polluting the global namespace just makes me feel dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `admin_menu` rather than `admin_init`, that's why you are getting error.

```
my_plugin_add_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page('Some Page', 'Some Page', 'manage_options', 'some-slug', 'my_plugin_some_page_callback');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_some_page_callback');

function my_plugin_some_page_callback() {
    echo 'Hello, world!';
}
```

You can also use anonymous `function` but organize your functions name is more cleaner way.